# SSH reverse tunneling alternative?

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have a Minecraft server running on my local Windows PC and a remote Debian server that I use to bypass my ports using SSH reverse tunneling.

My problem is that the ping is somewhat high, and I suspect it may have something to do with the SSH encryption (considering my server's low specs), so I was looking into a lightweight less-secure  alternative.

Note: The bandwidth in both my local machine and the server is considerably high, and there are not many players connected at once so that's why i suspect the virtual machine's low specs are my bottleneck. Also the ping is not unbearable, just would be nicer if it could improve.

Comment: What sort of delay are we talking about. Encryption wouldn’t add that much latency since it’s intranet traffic. What’s more likely is the specifications of the VM are simply not adequate for the Minecraft server which is heavily IO dependent (specifically memory). The alternative is to forward ports directly to the server but I assume you can’t do that

Comment: Yeah I can't forward ports directly, my ISP gives me a NAT so I share my public IP with like other 100 people. The remote server has only 2 cores and 1 GB of memory and the SSH tunneling seems to consume close to nothing memory so I don't think it matters. CPU instead stays around 50% on heavy traffic.  The Minecraft Server resides in my 32GB 8 cores local machine, so I don't think that is a problem. Even if I can spare 10ms of in-game ping by using a non-encrypting tunneling alternative would be nice.

Comment: An encrypted tunnel would have more like 1-3 ms overhead. Encrypted tunnel isn’t the source of your performance issues

Comment: What's the raw (unencrypted) ping time from your computer to the Debian server (and also from the other users to the server)? If those are high, there's nothing you can do at the protocol level to speed it up.